# Can this pandas workflow be converted to dask?

Tags: python, pandas, bioinformatics, dask

Please be nice - I'm not a proper programmer, I'm a scientist and I've read as many docs on this as I can find (they're a bit sparse).

I'm trying to convert this pandas code into dash because my input file is ~0.5TB with gz and it loads too slowly in native pandas. I have a 3 TB machine, btw.

This is an example of what I'm doing with pandas:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['chr1',33329,17,'''33)'6'4?1&AB=?+..''','''X%&=E&!%,0("&"Y&!'''],
                    ['chr1',33330,15,'''6+'/7=1@><C1*'*''','''X%=E!%,("&"Y&&!'''],
                    ['chr1',33331,13,'''2*3A@/9@CC3--''','''X%E!%,("&"Y&!'''],
                    ['chr1',33332,1,'''4**(,:3)+7-@<(0-''','''X%&E&!%,0("&"Y&!'''],
                    ['chr1',33333,2,'''66(/C=*42A:.&*''','''X%=&!%0("&"&&!''']],
                 columns = ['chrom','pos','depth','phred','map'])

df.loc[:,'phred'] = [(sum(map(ord,i))-len(i)*33)/len(i) for i in df.loc[:,"phred"]]
df.loc[:,"map"] = [(sum(map(ord,i)))/len(i) for i in df.loc[:,"map"]]
df = df.astype({'phred': 'int32', 'map': 'int32'})
df.query('(depth < 10) | (phred < 7) | (map < 10)', inplace=True)
for chrom, df_tmp in df.groupby('chrom'):
    df_end = df_tmp[~((df_tmp.pos.shift(0) == df_tmp.pos.shift(-1)-1))]
    df_start = df_tmp[~((df_tmp.pos.shift(0) == df_tmp.pos.shift(+1)+1))]
    for start, end in zip(df_start.pos, df_end.pos):
        print (start, end)
```

Gives

```
33332 33333
```

This works (to find regions of a cancer genome with no data) and it's optimised as much as I know how.

I load the real thing like:

```
df = pd.read_csv(
    '/Users/liamm/Downloads/test_head33333.tsv.gz',
     sep='\t',
    header=None,
    index_col=None,
    usecols=[0,1,3,5,6],
    names = ['chrom','pos','depth','phred','map']
)
```

and I can do the same with Dask (way faster!):

```
df = dd.read_csv(
    '/Users/liamm/Downloads/test_head33333.tsv.gz',
     sep='\t',
    header=None,
    usecols=[0,1,3,5,6],
    compression='gzip',
    blocksize=None,
    names = ['chrom','pos','depth','phred','map']
)
```

but i'm stuck here:

```
ff=[(sum(map(ord,i))-len(i)*33)/len(i) for i in df.loc[:,"phred"]]
df['phred'] = ff
```

Error: Column assignment doesn't support type list

Question - is this sort of thing possible? If so are there good tutes somewhere? I need to convert the whole block of pandas code above.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be great to add the expected output too. It looks to me that you can get rid of your loops.

Comment: The outcome from the working example I gave is '33332 33333'. You can copy paste that chunk of code and run it to get that.

Comment: Here is a blog post about high-performance pandas (author is a pandas core contributor, I believe):  https://tomaugspurger.github.io/modern-4-performance

Answer (score 1):

You created list comprehensions to transform 'Fred' and 'map'; I converted these list comps to functions, and wrapped the functions in `np.vectorize()`.

```
def func_p(p):
    return (sum(map(ord, p)) - len(p) * 33) / len(p)

def func_m(m):
    return (sum(map(ord, m)))  / len(m)

vec_func_p = np.vectorize(func_p)
vec_func_m = np.vectorize(func_m)
```

`np.vectorize()` does not make code faster, but it does let you write a function with scalar inputs and outputs, and convert it to a function that takes array inputs and outputs.

The benefit is that we can now pass pandas Series to these functions (I also added the type conversion to this step):

```
df.loc[:, 'phred'] = vec_func_p( df.loc[:, 'phred']).astype(np.int32)
df.loc[:, 'map'] = vec_func_m( df.loc[:, 'map']).astype(np.int32)
```

Replacing the list comprehensions with these new functions gives the same results as your version (33332 33333).

Comment: Thanks for ur ideas @jsmart. As you know my goal here is to get the whole thing to run in Dask. The main issue with my original code and ur suggestions is this error 'Not all divisions are known, can't align partitions. Please use `set_index` to set the index.' Jcrist explains the issue on the 8th Oct 2018 here https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/2690 . So unless these functions can return a modified version of the same Series I don't think that what I want to do is possible.

Comment: Q1:  Is there a publicly-available data set with the 5 columns of interest?  I'd like to learn Dask with real-world data.

Comment: Q2:  Could you add a column to the original data frame?  New column would be the same for each position within a consecutive run, but different consecutive runs would  have a different value.  At the end (possibly post-Dask), you could use `groupby()` to get min and max position for each (chromosome, key) pair.

Answer (score 1):

@rpanai noted that you could eliminate the `for` loops.  The following example uses `groupby()` (and a couple helper columns) to find the start and end position for each contiguous sequence of positions.

Using only pandas built-in functions should be compatible with Dask (and fast).

First, create demo data frame with multiple chromosomes and multiple  contiguous blocks of positions:

```
data1 = {
    'chrom' : 'chrom_1',
    'pos' : [1000, 1001, 1002, 
             2000, 2001, 2002, 2003]}
data2 = {
    'chrom' : 'chrom_2',
    'pos' : [30000, 30001, 30002, 30003, 30004, 
             40000, 40001, 40002, 40003, 40004, 40005]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1).append( pd.DataFrame(data2) )
```

Second, create two helper functions:

- `rank` is a sequential counter for each group;
- `key` is constant for positions in a contiguous 'run' of positions.

```
df['rank'] = df.groupby('chrom')['pos'].rank(method='first')
df['key'] = df['pos'] - df['rank']
```

Third, group by `chrom` and `key` to create a groupby object for each contiguous block of positions, then use `min` and `max` to find start and end value for the positions.

```
result = (df.groupby(['chrom', 'key'])['pos']
            .agg(['min', 'max'])
            .droplevel('key')
            .rename(columns={'min': 'start', 'max': 'end'})
         )
print(result)

         start    end
chrom                
chrom_1   1000   1002
chrom_1   2000   2003
chrom_2  30000  30004
chrom_2  40000  40005
```